# How change the header color?

Tags: headers, header-image

I want to change the balck color in the header and also the font color in the same place?

**Update:** I am using the Twenty Ten 1.3 theme

[image]

Comment: What theme are you using? Do you want it to be configurable from a settings page?

Comment: Please read and follow our [nice guide on asking questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): Be specific, make it relevant to others, and be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

(1) In your twentyten theme's style.css file, find this rule:

```
#access {
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}
```

the black color comes from this property ang change it to your liking: `background: #000;`

(2) In your twentyten theme's style.css file, find this rule:

```
#access a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

font color comes from this property and change it to your liking: `color: #aaa;`